# How can one optimally store decimal digits in binary?

Tags: binary, decimal, storage

I don't need this for anything, but I was just curious about it.

The [Wikipedia article about QR codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage) says that storing one decimal number takes 3⅓ bits per digit. Obviously you can't have a third of a bit, so I assume this is the average number of bits it takes to store any given digit.

Two questions:

1. Is it true that you can store decimal digits in 3⅓ bits, on average?
2. True or not, how *can* you store decimal digits in binary optimally?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question would be a better fit for Software Engineering or not, so I'm fine if it needs to be moved.

Comment: The 3 and 1/3 seems to be an estimate. Assuming it was correct you should be able to store a three-digit decimal number with 10 bits. 10 bits actually allow for 1024 unique values, so there's some extra room there. As for `how can you store decimal digits in binary optimally` - you can't, there's always going to be the potential for rounding errors. Well, you can store _integer_ values accurately within a given range by having extra space, but not real numbers, like 1/3.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use k bits to store n digits whenever 2<sup>k</sup>≥10<sup>n</sup>.  In particular though, you want to choose values where the values are close (choose the smallest k for a given n).  With that you find

- 4 bits for 1 digit (BCD)
- 7 bits for 2 digits
- 10 bits for 3 digits (BCT)
- 103 bits for 31 digits

Another interesting possibility is using 53 bits to store 15 digits + 1 non-zero digit.  This can be useful for decimal floating point where the leading mantissa digit is always non-zero.